# CruiseControl.Net & Msbuild - msbuild task finish but CCNet process not?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, msbuild

I am using MSBuild with CruiseControl.NET to make automatic build. When I force msbuild to make build through CruiseControl Web Dashboard, it builds the project and make output file but Cruise Control tasks will not stopped. It is contentiously running (Activity : Building ) and I am not able to stop it.

For running msbuild again , I have to restart my pc again.

My ccnet.config file :-

```
<project name="Monopoker Cash Phone App">

    <state type="state" directory="C:\MonopokerCashState\State" />
    <workingDirectory>C:\Project\MonopokerCC\monopoker</workingDirectory>
    <artifactDirectory>C:\Project\MonopokerCC</artifactDirectory>
    <tasks>
       <msbuild>
          <executable>C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\MSBuild.exe</executable>
          <workingDirectory>C:\Project\MonopokerCC\monopoker\MonoPoker</workingDirectory>
          <projectFile>MonoPoker.csproj</projectFile>
          <buildArgs>/p:Configuration=PhoneRelease /p:AndroidSdkDirectory=C:\android-sdk /t:SignAndroidPackage /v:diag</buildArgs>
          <targets>Clean</targets>
          <logger>C:\Program Files (x86)\CruiseControl.NET\server\ThoughtWorks.CruiseControl.MsBuild.dll</logger>
        </msbuild>
   </tasks>
</project>
```

[image]